# Read Config variable at webroot file

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, app-config

In my application,I already set a variable like config in core.php such as

**core.php**

```
$websetting = array(
    'mydomain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@xyz.com',
    'supportEmail' => 'support@xyz.com',
    'infoEmail' => 'info@xyz.com',
    'accountEmail' => 'accounts@xyz.com',
    'facebook' => 'facebook.com/xyz',
    'twitter' => 'twitter.com/@xyz'
);

Configure::write('WebsiteSetting', $websetting);
```

Now I create a one morning.php file in cj in webroot. So my path is like: `webroot/cj/morning.php`

In morning.php I try to read `Configure::read('WebsiteSetting.mydomain')`.

```
<?php
echo Configure::read('WebsiteSetting.mydomain');
?>
```

What happened :

Comment: Use the framework. Create a controller/action/view that does what you want. Don't try and invent things. There is no quick and easy way to do this and it can be achieved easily the "proper" way.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you do that?
The morning.php file in your webroot has absolutely no information about cake.
You would need to copy the index.php and modify it (remove the dispatching) so that all the cake stuff is included before trying to use cake functionality like Configure..

What exactly are you trying to achieve?
Use the normal controller/action stuff to create your page - no matter what context it is.

Comment: Thanks,I am working on modification project and I try to make global setting.I know this is a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller set a variable to your view...

Controller:

```
$this->set('mydomain', Configure::read('WebsiteSetting.mydomain'));
```

View:

```
echo $mydomain;
```

If it is used in a layout set the variable from beforeFilter or beforeRender

Comment: this file is in webroot/cj/morning.php.it has no controller and also layout.

Comment: Why would you want to circumvent Cake's MVC? It is well possible to include legacy code into a Cake app, by simply creating a controller and actions for it.

Comment: How is it be circumventing Cake's patterns, I merely explained how to pass a variable from the controller to the view.